# Create new resource directly in Laravel Nova with nested collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Nova. I have a resource of a Company that should have an address. The address is stored in a different global Address resource. How can I directly add the Address info when creating a Company?

That's why I have this Fields now:

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('Company name', 'name')->sortable()->rules('required', 'max:255'),
        Text::make('Website', 'website')->hideFromIndex()->rules('nullable', 'url'),
        Markdown::make('Info')->alwaysShow(),
        BelongsTo::make('User')->searchable()->rules('required'),

        ## Address Resource needs
        Place::make('Streetname and number', 'address.address')->hideWhenUpdating(),
        Text::make('City', 'address.city')->hideWhenUpdating(),
        Text::make('Zipcode', 'address.postcode')->hideWhenUpdating(),
        Text::make('Latitude', 'address.latitude')->hideWhenUpdating(),
        Text::make('Longitude', 'address.longitude')->hideWhenUpdating(),

        // BelongsTo::make('Address')->searchable()->rules('required')->hideWhenCreating(),
    ];
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I can't see any mention of storing nested relations in the documentation; is that possible?

Comment: From Laravel Nova docs
Customizing Resource Classes

You can customize the resource class used by the relation field by setting the second and third parameters of the make method:

```BelongsTo::make('Author', 'author', 'App\Nova\User');```

Comment: Yes, that's what you see being commented out and not where my question is about.

Comment: Maybe this package does what you want: https://novapackages.com/packages/yassi/nova-nested-form

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: If you still not solved this issue then Would please explain more this with more information? Can't understand actual requirement so.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel Nova 4 you can add `->showCreateRelationButton()` to your BelongsTo field. In result you get

```
Fields\BelongsTo::make('Address', Address::class)->showCreateRelationButton()
```

[image]

And after you click "+" you can see the modal for creating related model

[image]